# Unable to add information to scalable table

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking to create a function that will add information to my table as well as adding a row in the process. I have gathered most of the code below from various sources and this is my best attempt. I feel as though I'm missing a small yet pivotal piece of code. Can someone please see if they can see why this isn't working - thanks.

Form:

```
            <label>Name: </label><input id="customerName" class ="form- 
        control" type="text" name="Name of Customer" required></input>
        </br>

        <label>Email Address: </label><input id="customerEmail" class 
         ="form-control" type="email" name="Email Address" required></input>
        </br>

        <label>Phone no.: </label><input id="customerPhone" class ="form- 
        control" type="number" name="Phone No." required></input>
        </br>

        <label>Date & Time of Test Drive: </label><input 
         id="customerDate" class ="form-control" type="datetime-local" 
         name="Date & Time of Test Drive" required></input>
        </br>

        <input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="AddData()"></input>
```

Table:

```
<table id="tblAppts" style="width:60%; border: 1px solid black" border="1" 
align="center">

<thead>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Email</th> 
<th>Phone Number</th>
<th>Date/Time of Appt</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Danny O'Sullivan</td>
<td>dannyosullivan1@gmail.com</td>
<td>0858415570</td>
<td>19/07/2019 12:30</td>
</tr>

  <tr>
<td>Rob O'Keefe</td>
<td>rob@hotmail.com</td>
<td>0812445432</td>
<td>19/08/2019 12:30</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Danny Crowley</td>
<td>crwley@gmail.com</td>
<td>0858413213</td>
<td>19/07/2019 13:30</td>
</tr>

  <tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
function addData() {

    var name = document.getElementById("customerName").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("customerEmail").value;
    var phone = document.getElementById("customerPhone").value;
    var date = document.getElementById("customerDate").value;

var tableRef = document.getElementById('tblAppts').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

// Insert a row in the table at the last row
var newRow   = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);

// Insert a cell in the row at index 0
var nameCell  = newRow.insertCell(0);
var emailCell  = newRow.insertCell(1);
var phoneCell  = newRow.insertCell(2);
var dateCell  = newRow.insertCell(3);

nameCell.innerHTML = customerName;
emailCell.innerHTML = customerEmail;
phoneCell.innerHTML = customerPhone;
dateCell.innerHTML = customerDate;

var newText  = document.createTextNode('New row');
newCell.appendChild(newText);

        }
```

Comment: Please check the answer, let me know if it is what you wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your submit button is calling to the incorrect method, remember that JavaScript it is [Case Sensitive](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/javascript-the-definitive/0596000480/ch02s02.html). Also it is not necessary the `</input>`

Wrong:

```
<input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="AddData()"></input>
```

Right:

```
<input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="addData()">
```

I have made some fixes in your code: `customerName`, `customerEmail`, `customerPhone`, `customerDate` are **undefined**. I used your already defined variables `name`, `email`, `phone` and `date` instead.

Also the method `newCell` does not exist.

```js
function addData() {

    var name = document.getElementById("customerName").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("customerEmail").value;
    var phone = document.getElementById("customerPhone").value;
    var date = document.getElementById("customerDate").value;

    var tableRef = document.getElementById('tblAppts').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

    // Insert a row in the table at the last row
    var newRow   = tableRef.insertRow(tableRef.rows.length);

    // Insert a cell in the row at index 0
    var nameCell  = newRow.insertCell(0);
    var emailCell  = newRow.insertCell(1);
    var phoneCell  = newRow.insertCell(2);
    var dateCell  = newRow.insertCell(3);

    nameCell.innerHTML = name;
    emailCell.innerHTML = email;
    phoneCell.innerHTML = phone;
    dateCell.innerHTML = date;

    var newText  = document.createTextNode('New row');
}
```

```html
<label>Name: </label><input id="customerName" class ="form-control" type="text" name="Name of Customer" required></input>

</br>
<label>Email Address: </label><input id="customerEmail" class="form-control" type="email" name="Email Address" required></input>
</br>

<label>Phone no.: </label><input id="customerPhone" class ="form-control" type="number" name="Phone No." required></input>
</br>

<label>Date & Time of Test Drive: </label><input id="customerDate" class ="form-control" type="datetime-local" name="Date & Time of Test Drive" required></input>
</br>

<input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="addData()">
  
<table id="tblAppts" style="width:60%; border: 1px solid black" border="1" 
align="center">

<thead>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Email</th> 
<th>Phone Number</th>
<th>Date/Time of Appt</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Danny O'Sullivan</td>
<td>dannyosullivan1@gmail.com</td>
<td>0858415570</td>
<td>19/07/2019 12:30</td>
</tr>

  <tr>
<td>Rob O'Keefe</td>
<td>rob@hotmail.com</td>
<td>0812445432</td>
<td>19/08/2019 12:30</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Danny Crowley</td>
<td>crwley@gmail.com</td>
<td>0858413213</td>
<td>19/07/2019 13:30</td>
</tr>

  <tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is great. The code is working when I run it on this page but not on my web app - I should have mentioned before that the form and the table are on two separate html pages. Should it work the same, or are there alterations I can make on this code?

Comment: In that case you only have to change the "addData" in your submit button, and the other depends of how are you rendering from your server. Btw you can check it as an answer ;)

Comment: Can you please elaborate on changing the addData in my submit button?

Comment: It is actually changing from AddData to addData, the first letter in lowercase. You can see it in my response of the HTML at line 13 <input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="addData()">
An upvote is really helpful :)

Comment: I have upvoted your answer but unfortunately I need 15 rep for it to appear! I am almost there so I will come back to this when I have reached that :) thanks for your help!